# Cleaning the Xbox Lens

Tags: xbox-360, hardware

What is the fast, most efficient way to clean your Xbox 360 lens? I have all the knowledge of computers, but the gaming systems are foreign to me.
I believe it is the lens that is broken, dirty or scratched as the system keeps freezing up without warning on various gamins during the loading.

Comment: bring it in for service in a shop, don't open it yourself as that will void the warrantee

Comment: The warrantee is already broken. I bought it used at GameStop about 3 years ago. But thank you for the advice.

Comment: also freezing can also be caused by overheating

Comment: We have looked into that. The overheating makes sense if it didn't freeze during boot for the first play of the day, combined with the open ventilated area and the chill of the house (around 70 degrees Fahrenheit). I admit it could be the cause but I don't believe it is.

Comment: my old PS3 tends to freeze when I activate graphical "cheats" but is fine otherwise, a badly fitted heatsink will do the trick

Comment: The power brick also tends to overheat - if you have that somewhere with inadequate ventilation, you might consider moving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to clean the lense is to go out and buy a cleaning disc. These are made specifically to clean gaming systems/DVD players, so it wouldn't damage the Xbox. ( I used one of these on a DVD player and it worked well.) If it is the actual lense, you would have to service it.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the optical drive out of the "original style" Xbox 360 is a [34 step process, according to this guide on iFixit](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Xbox+360+Optical+Drive+Removal/3358).  They even use some specialized tools in the process, without which it will probably be more complex.  Then you'd have to disassemble the drive itself to get at the lens.

You could attempt to use a [CD/DVD cleaning kit](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00008EM7U) which is a disc you can put into the drive and will (supposedly) clean the lens.  I've had hit-or-miss luck with this in various devices, though.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have a CD-Player cleaner disk. It had a tiny brush glued to it. It had limited success, although it was better than having to crack it open and Q-tip it. Sometimes you need to really get at it though. I had a laptop that I'd just about given up on (q-tip and alcohol wouldn't work) until I just used my finger to clean the lens, now it works. Don't forget to clean (mild soap and warm water) and polish (plastic polish, extra fine scratch remover) your disks.